# What does "believe it or not " mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I often hear people saying something by starting their sentence with *believe it or not*. What does people mean when they say *believe it or not* ?. Does it mean that although the statement that the person is making does not seem to be true at first glance, that is the fact actually and he doesn't care if you are not believing his statement?

Comment: Answer [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/believe+it+or+not) or [here](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/believe-it-or-not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means they are about to say something surprising or unbelievable, but it is true even if you don't believe it.

It is effectively:

"[Whether you]believe it or not,this statement is true."